# Android -Java - How to use a Countdown Timer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I am trying to put a `Countdown timer` using a `TextView` inside my `Android studio` project. I have been looking at other posts but I haven't been getting any good information. I want the *simplest* way to make an easy `Countdown timer`. Thanks in advance!

**Countdown Timer:**

```
CountDownTimer Count = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    timerText.setText("Seconds remaining: " + ((millisUntilFinished/ 1000) ));
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    timerText.setText("Time Done...");
                }
            };
            Count.start();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7966996/7427111

Comment: Please post the code that you are using and also the logcat by editing the question.

Comment: [**Github Link for Timer**](https://github.com/dhavaljardosh/Android-Studio-Projects/blob/master/EggTimer/app/src/main/java/com/example/jardosh/eggtimer/MainActivity.java), check if you can get some help from here.

Comment: `'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`, this means you are trying to set text to something which is not referenced properly. Show your java code as well.

Comment: Oops! I just noticed, i havent assigned my TextView Sorry guys!

Comment: @Dhaval Jardosh  And also, another error, my timer simply just displays "time" without me assigning it, Im going to show my whole java class. But I am no longer getting a NullPointerExexption